# Can a variable frequency drive be connected to a motor driving a hammer mill to save energy?

Tags: energy

Inductive motors are largely used to drive pumps, hammer mills etc. When used with pumps are there benefits of connecting a Variable Frequency Drive(VFD) to a motor. Does tha same hold true of driving a hammer mill, especially in respect of saving energy is concerned, without compromising milling efficiency?

Comment: What kind of motor are we talking here? Asynchronous or synchronous motor?

Comment: Single or three phase motor?  What size?  Can the application tolerate running at reduced speed, or is it a constant speed application?

Comment: Please fix the title of your question ("harmer") and capitalise the first word.

Comment: This is unanswerable without details of the mechanical process being powered which are far beyond the scope of what belongs on this site.  Voting to close.

Comment: If you want to save energy just leave the hammer mill motor disconnected, Job done. Also voting to close this unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

If the mill runs at nominally 1000rpm, then running at 800rpm would almost certainly compromise its rate of milling. However, it would also consume less power. Whether you regard this as 'compromise the efficiency of the mill' is up to how you define 'efficiency'.

It might mill as finely at lower rpm than it did at rated speed, or it might produce a coarser product. Again your definition of efficiency is what determines whether this difference would be a compromise or not.

Comment: Efficiency, is the ratio of useful mechanical power divide by the power given to the machine.

Comment: Also, the way you reduce the speed affect your efficiency as an example you can reduce the speed of a asynchronous machine by adding resistance to the rotor, but you are reducing the power efficiency.

Comment: @MathieuL **Your** definition of efficiency is that. Who knows what the OP's definition is. VFDs are usually three phase SMPS, with efficiencies (we know what that means here, in the context of a power converter) typically in the 90%+ region.

Comment: In a context of energy, I am pretty sure that the OP mean reducing the power the machine consume without compromising the efficiency of the machine ex: 800 W, n = 0.9 vs 500 W, n = 0.6. The energy consume is reduce but the efficiency is reduce too.

Answer (score 1):

A VFD saves the energy when compared to direct start when there are many turns on/off. A vfd doesn't save any energy when operating at nominal speed, also the vfd has its own loss, so the total energy consumption is increased. However with use of vfd you can decrease speed of motor and you can have a soft start. If your machine just turns on and spins the flywheel without stopping, then you don't need a vfd.